# Is there a event that is fired when fullscreen transition ends

Tags: highcharts, fullscreen

I have an app where I want to switch Highcharts charts into full screen mode. Unfortunately the charts are only changing their width but not there height. So I'm looking for a way to get notified when the container for the charts as reached its new size and then update the size for the chart. The only way I see so far is a simple timeout but this is nothing I can't rely on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setSize()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize%28%29) function and have influence on both parameters.

EDIT:
You can check resolution of display by:

window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth

and size of chart by $('#chartDiv').width();

Comment: The question was more about to get noticed when the container reached its full screen size